# Recommended plugin for SQL server 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Is there any recommended plugin for SQL server 2008 to use when you are working as database administration, Business Intelligence developer or Database developer?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Recommended tools for SQL Server Developers & DBA](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/10787/recommended-tools-for-sql-server-developers-dba)

Comment: Every developer finds their own set of tools to be most helpful, and while it's great to see some lists like this, they really don't have a home here. Sorry lads. Now, if you wanna start writing a column on BlogOverflow every so often for the site for new tools that you've found that help the community, come on with 'em.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- [SentryOne Plan Explorer](https://sentryone.com/plan-explorer/) (free) - analyze execution plans in a way you could never do with Management Studio alone ([I also wrote a demo kit here](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/plan-explorer-3-0-demo-kit))
- [SSMS Tools Pack](http://ssmstoolspack.com/) (free) - lots of valuable features here - snippets, connection color coding that works, CRUD generation, and query execution history

Comment: Sentry Plan Explorer has been a life saver more than once, great product. Tools Pack is an essential add-in for SSMS

Answer (score -1):

I have written SSMSBoost add-in (www.ssmsboost.com).

I develop databases since SQL Server 6.5 and like clear and quick interface of SSMS, but it definitely lacks some productivity features - so that motivated me to improve it.

Here is a list of features:

- Script object located at cursor position directly from SQL Editor. Shortcut:[F2]
- Locate object: quickly find object located at cursor position in object explorer. Shortcut:[Ctrl-F2]
- Track current database in ObjectExplorer permanently
- Locate current database in ObjectExplorer
- Search for objects using wildcards
- QuickConnection Switch combobox on SSMSBoost toolbar allows switching connection in SQLEditor
- Preferred connections management: "remember" frequently used server/databases, quickly swith between them
- Shortcuts editor - feature, that is missing in SSMS2008, but is coming in SSMS2012
- Define macros with existing commands
- Auto replacements
- Connection coloring - in more useful way
- Server aliases in quick connection switch combobox

SSMS2012 support is coming. I will always release "community" edition in some days, that will be functional after trial period, but with some small limitations.

Comment: Although your answer is somewhat relevant to the OP's question, you're punting a commercial product.  That's really pushing the edges of outright spam here.

Comment: ok, sorry. I am preparing free edition now ;)